# ws + express how to connect to a websocket

Tags: node.js, websocket

I'm attempting to use web sockets for the first time ever and after some research I have decided to use ws.

I'm also using express but I didn't see anything special for that, only if I was using it server side (I believe but I'm still a bit confused on web sockets in general). I just need to connect to a web socket and send a ping request and wait for the response.

I have a default express application with:

`bin/www`

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const app = require("../app");
const debug = require("debug")("myapp:server");
const http = require("http");
const WebSocket = require("ws");
const ws = new WebSocket("ws://address-to-connect");

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || "3000");
app.set("port", port);

var server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port);
server.on("error", onError);
server.on("listening", onListening);

function normalizePort(val) {
    let port = parseInt(val, 10);

    if (isNaN(port)) {
        return val;
    }

    if (port >= 0) {
        return port;
    }

    return false;
}

function onError(error) {
    if (error.syscall !== "listen") {
        throw error;
    }

    var bind = typeof port === "string"
        ? "Pipe " + port
        : "Port " + port;

    switch (error.code) {
        case "EACCES":
            console.error(bind + " requires elevated privileges");
            process.exit(1);
            break;
        case "EADDRINUSE":
            console.error(bind + " is already in use");
            process.exit(1);
            break;
        default:
            throw error;
    }
}

function onListening() {
    let addr = server.address();
    let bind = typeof addr === "string"
        ? "pipe " + addr
        : "port " + addr.port;

    debug("Listening on " + bind);

    ws.on("open", function open() {
        if (error) throw error;

        ws.send("PING");
    });

    ws.on("message", function incoming(data) {
        if (error) throw error;

        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

This however just throws me an error of `events.js:182 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event Error: connect ECONNREFUSED`

I tried researching this error and from what I gathered it's about a port in use already but this is the only application I have running.

In case it's needed, my app.js looks like:

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    res.locals.message = err.message;
    res.locals.error = req.app.get("env") == "development" ? err : {};

    res.status(err.status || 500);
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: 1. Your app should act like ws client or server?
2. Add `ws.on('error', (error) => console.error)` listener, to handle `Unhandled 'error'` error.